# What does 'char (&) [13]' mean?

Tags: c++, c++11

As an old c++ programmer,  I'm learning c++11 recently. When reading *Effective Mordern C++*, I found the interesting type:

```
char (&) [13]
```

When passing an array to a function template requiring T&:

```
template<typename T>
void funcTemplate1(T& param)
{
    std::cout << boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr<T>().pretty_name() << std::endl;
}
void main()
{
    char szHello[] = "Hello, World";
    funcTemplate1(szHello);
}
```

It output :

```
char (&) [13]
```

Never have seen that. What does is mean?

Comment: It's a reference to an array of thirteen `char`.

Comment: I figured out it may mean a reference to a char [13] array, but why the parentheses?

Comment: Thanks @Peter, It seems that I can't use it directly as char (&)[13] = szHello;  There will be compile errors;

Comment: Parentheses are because of C++ syntax weirdness that requires to put variable name in the middle `char ( & sz_text )[13] = szHello;` and read it with spiral rule. Actually with C++11 it is possible to write it in more readable manner, like `ref<array<13, char>> sz_text = szHello;` or (with automatic type deduction) `const auto & sz_text = szHello;`.

Comment: For the same reason that `char *x[13]` is an array of 13 pointers, and `char (*x)[13]` is a pointer to an array of 13 char.    Except it is not possible to have an array of references so `char &x[13]` won't compile.

Comment: `char (&)[13]` is a type.  To declare a variable, you need a name of the variable as well as its type.   So you would need `char(&x)[13] = szHello`

Comment: @Peter Oh, thanks a lot. That's right.

Comment: @VTT Thanks a lot. I've tried it out. It worked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If we insert the lost function parameter name, it becomes:

```
char (&param) [13]
```

You're undoubtedly familiar with this:

```
char param[13]
```

Which of course is an array of 13 characters.  Adding the `&` means it is a reference to the same.  The parentheses are needed because it is a reference to an array, not an array of references.